# min length rule doesn't accept message in Yii

Tags: yii, rule

the following code in my Model Rules function in Yii

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('mail, firstname, lastname, number, question, time', 'required','message'=>'{attribute} نمی تواند خالی باشد'),
        array('status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true,'message'=>'{attribute} فقط مقادیر عددی مجاز است'),
        array('mail, firstname, lastname, number', 'length', 'max'=>45,'message'=>'حداکثر طول {attribute} ۴۵ کارکتر می باشد'),
        array('question','length','min'=>10,'message'=>'حداقل طول سوال ۱۰ کارکتر می باشد'),
        array('mail','email','message'=>'ایمیل وارد شده حقیقی نمی باشد'),
        array('time','unsafe'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, mail, firstname, lastname, number, question, time, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

all the messages work correctly except which I defined for minimum of length

```
array('question','length','min'=>10,'message'=>'حداقل طول سوال ۱۰ کارکتر می باشد'),
```

it always return the default of Yii which means  **پرسش is too short (minimum is 10 characters).**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `message` property is used [**only**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStringValidator#c10601) when the field is not of some exact length specified by [`is` property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStringValidator#is-detail). For a custom minimum length message use [`tooShort` property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStringValidator#tooShort-detail):

```
array('question','length','min'=>10,'tooShort'=>'حداقل طول سوال ۱۰ کارکتر می باشد'),
```